# Tensorflow Keras Different Inference Results Depending on Batch Size

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, gpu

During inference, with a tf2 keras eager model in python using the GPU, I expect the same inference result for an input regardless of whether I have batched my inference data. For example I expect the following to be true regardless of the size of images but they are not:

```
discriminator(images[:10], training=False) == discriminator(images, training=False)[:10]
```

Is this difference related to floating point errors on the GPU? This can result in differences of E-6 when inferring 64x(28,28) images compared with 128 images and extracting the desired 64 which I think is not insignificant.

```
import numpy as np
#images.shape=(128,28,28,1)
discriminator=make_discriminator_model()
Dlogits1=discriminator(images[:64], training=False)
Dlogits2=discriminator(images, training=False)
delta=np.sum(Dlogits1-Dlogits2[:64])  #delta=-1.2e-6
Dlogits3=discriminator(images, training=False)
delta3=np.sum(Dlogits3-Dlogits2 #delta3=0


import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers    
def make_discriminator_model():
 model = tf.keras.Sequential()
 model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same',input_shape=[28, 28, 1]))
 model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
 model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
 model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
 model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
 model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
 model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
 model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
 model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
 model.add(layers.Flatten())
 model.add(layers.Dense(1))
 return model
```

Comment: I believe it’s commonly expected that batching can have *some* impact on results, with a risk of that impact being negative for larger batch sizes. Beyond the randomness you mention, it makes a difference if you run one example, update the model, then run the next example, or run both and apply the combined result. It’s similar to but somewhat distinct from learning rate effects.